# How do I pass an array as parameter from Ipython notebook to an html file, which contains some javascript functions?

Tags: javascript, html, jupyter-notebook

I have one html file (file.html) which contains a javascript function as below :

### file.html

```
<html>
 <head> 
 </head>
<script>
    function demo()
    {
       do something using param1;
    }
</script>
</html>
```

'Param1' is the array that I need to pass from an IPython notebook everytime I call this file.html. The requirement is to show the the output of file.html in the notebook itself which I am doing using the following commands.

```
from IPython.display import IFrame
IFrame('file.html', width=1000, height=550)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to pass your array as an URL parameter.

Say your array is `{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'}` - you can do `IFrame('file.html?param1=a,b,c,d', width=1000, height=550)` and then fetch url parameters from javascript. It's up to you how you format your array as a text string tho.

About fetching url parameters : there is no standard way to do that in javascript [but here is an implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-url-parameter).

Then do whatever the you need/want with it inside `demo()`.

Comment: I am Calling it in this way, but not getting the params in js.

IFrame('../net-vis/WebContent/html/index.html?abc=3', width=1200, height=800)

Comment: Passing parameters like IFrame('file.html?param1=a,b,c,d', width=1000, height=550) does not work in practice!